# DOMDocument saving html with extra tags

Tags: php, dom

I am using HTMLDom to manipulate a string, rather than a complete webpage. When I use `saveHTML()` it automatically throws in `doctype` and `html` tags.

```
$str = 'frament containing html';
$str = utf8_encode($str);
$doc->LoadHTML($str);
...do stuff...
$str = $doc->saveHTML();
```

What is the correct way to save a fragment of HTML without the automatic inclusion of extra tags. Failing that; the correct method to remove these extra tags?

I used an html parser [to avoid using regex's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/817379), so it seems a little counter-intuitive to have to use them on the output of a parser.

Comment: Are you using PHPs ext/dom or the SimpleHtmlDOM library (or another library)? Your example source is incomplete.

Comment: I am using PHPs ext/dom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPs DOMDocument repairs the document if you load HTML. That means it adds the `html` and `body` elements.

So you need to fetch all nodes inside `body` and save them as HTML.

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
<h1>Hello World</h1>
Text
<!-- comment -->
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$result = '';
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/html/body/node()') as $node) {
  $result .= $dom->saveHtml($node);
}

echo $result;
```

Here is another option, but it is not available everywhere yet. PHP added `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` and `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` options.

```
$dom->loadHtml($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

### PHP <= 5.3

The first an best option would be to update the PHP. PHP 5.3 is no longer maintained.

The second option is using DOMDocument::saveXML($node, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG). This will generate an XML (XHTML) fragment, but should be enough for the most cases.

The last option would be using the string functions.

Comment: I tried this but I get `Warning: DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given`. My site is on a server running PHP 5.3.3